# Edit child node XML with DOM in PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing, dom, xml-parsing

I'm trying to implement functionality to edit a XML-based news feed from a PHP-powered web app. However, it doesn't seem to ever save.

The XML file I'm working with is as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<issues>                                                                    
        <issue>
            <issue_id>1</issue_id>
            <issue_name>Don't double my rates!</issue_name>
            <issue_body>Congress is on the verge of letting student rates double a week from today. Swing by the UC Lawn at 5:00 this Thursday to reach out to our Representatives and tell them: #DontDoubleMyRates!</issue_body></issue>
         <issue>
            <issue_id>2</issue_id>
            <issue_name>Proposed Senate Budget</issue_name>
            <issue_body>College Democrats are baffled by the proposed senate budget. This is our state, we must make our opinions heard! #NCGOPBudget #StopCuts</issue_body></issue>
         <issue>
            <issue_id>3</issue_id>
            <issue_name>Voter Suppression Law Invalidated!</issue_name>
            <issue_body>Join us in applauding the US Supreme Court for invalidating Arizona's voter-suppression law requiring that voters present proof of citizenship before voting!</issue_body></issue>
         <issue>
            <issue_id>4</issue_id>
            <issue_name>Here's an actual article I found interesting</issue_name>                    
            <issue_body>Actually, not really beacause I really didn't want to google for some arbitrary article to help test this out so here's a bunch of filler text to hopefully emulate at least the by-line of an article pertaining to the democratic party organization here on campus.</issue_body>
            </issue>
</issues>
```

Here is the relevant php script that tries to edit the pre-existing node:

```
<?php                                                                           
$newName = $_POST['name'];                                                  
$newBody = $_POST['body'];                                                  
$issue_id = $_POST['edit'];                                                 

$dom = new DOMDocument;                                                     
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;                                           
$dom->load('issues.xml');                                                   

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);                                                
$query = '/issues/issue';                                          

foreach($xpath->query($query) as $issue) {                                  
    $id = $issue->parentNode->getElementsByTagName("issue_id");         
    if($id->item($issue_id)->nodeValue = $issue_id) {                   
    $name = $issue->parentNode->getElementsByTagName("issue_name");       
    $body = $issue->parentNode->getElementsByTagName("issue_body");       
    $name->item($issue_id-1)->nodeValue = '$newName';                           
    $body->item($issue_id-1)->nodeValue = '$newBody';                        
    break;                                                                  
    }                                                                       
}                                                                           

    $dom->save("issues.xml");                                                   
?>
```

Here is the referring page which iterates through the child nodes until it finds the previously selected node's ID and then displays its info in a table.

```
<?php                                                                           
$issue_id = $_POST['edit'];                                                 
$issueArray = array(                                                        
'id' =>$_POST['id'],                                                        
'issue_name' => $_POST['issue_name'],                                       
'issue_body' => $_POST['issue_body'],                                       
);                                                                          

$dom = new DOMDocument;                                                     
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;                                           
$dom->load('issues.xml');                                                   

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);                                                
$query = '/issues/issue';                                          

$i = 0;                                                                     
echo "<body><form action='saveChanges.php' method='post'><table border='1'><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Body</th></tr>";

foreach($xpath->query($query) as $issue) {                                  
    $eventI = $issue->parentNode->getElementsByTagName("issue_id");         
    if($eventI->item($issue_id)->nodeValue = $issue_id) {                   
    $eventN = $issue->parentNode->getElementsByTagName("issue_name");       
    $eventP = $issue->parentNode->getElementsByTagName("issue_body");       
    print "<tr><td>'".$eventI->item($issue_id-1)->nodeValue."'></td><td>'".$eventN->item($issue_id-1)->nodeValue."'></td><td>'".$eventP->item($issue_id-1)->nodeValue."'</td></tr>";
    print "<tr><td></td><th>New Name</td><th>New Body</td></tr>";           
    print "<tr><td></td><td><input type='text' name='name'size='50'</input></td><td><input type='text' name='body' size='200'</input></td></tr>";
    print "<tr><td><input type='hidden' name='id' value='$issue_id'/></td><th><input type='submit' action='saveChanges.php' name='edit' method='post' value='Confirm Edit'/></th><th></th>";
    break;                                                                  
    }                                                                       
}                                                                           
print "</table></body>";                                                    
?>
```

I'm not that great at PHP, and even worse at parsing XML, any help to get this going in the right direction would be great!

Comment: This website here is for professional an enthusiast programmers. You probably want to try some other forum. As you ask for "into the right direction".

Comment: Um, I'm a CompSci major that was just tasked with XML manipulation for the first time, so I'm completely new to the subject. After hours of searching around and looking into it, I thought I'd ask for some assistance, since, you know, that's what this site is for. Figured it would be worth a shot. Didn't know I'd be met with elitists with sticks up their butts, though.

Comment: @ChrisDevWard Personally I don't think there was anything particularly wrong with your question, and I apologise if my answer came across as elitist. I was trying to help you.

Comment: @JamesHolderness No worries, your comment is a ton of help. That was more pointed towards hakre's condescending remark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are all sorts of problems in the code that is manipulating the DOM. Just looking at the contents of the for loop, you start with this:

```
$id = $issue->parentNode->getElementsByTagName("issue_id");
```

In the line above, you have taken the `$issue` that you enumerated in the for loop and then referenced its parent, which is the same for every issue, thus making the enumeration irrelevant.

You're then getting all `issue_id` elements in that tree, with which you do this:

```
if($id->item($issue_id)->nodeValue = $issue_id) {
```

Here you are using the `$issue_id` as an index, which assumes that an `issue_id` of 3 (for example) would always be the third issue, which probably isn't true.

Also a single `=` is an assignment, not a comparison, which I'm sure was not your intention.

The `$name` and `$body` lookups are the same:

```
$name = $issue->parentNode->getElementsByTagName("issue_name");       
$body = $issue->parentNode->getElementsByTagName("issue_body");
```

Again you're ignoring the `$issue` that has been enumerated and are working from the parent node, and then just getting all the child elements that match `issue_name` and `issue_body`.

And again you're using the `$issue_id` as an index:

```
$name->item($issue_id-1)->nodeValue = '$newName';                           
$body->item($issue_id-1)->nodeValue = '$newBody';
```

This time, though, you're using `$issue_id-1` - was there a reason for that?

Also when you use single quotes for a string in php, that doesn't expand the variable, so the name will always be set to the literal string `$newName` rather than value of that variable. You should either use double quotes, or better still, just assign the value directly.

This is more like what I would expect the code to look like:

```
foreach($xpath->query($query) as $issue) {        
    $id = $issue->getElementsByTagName("issue_id")->item(0);  
    if($id->nodeValue == $issue_id) {  
        $name = $issue->getElementsByTagName("issue_name")->item(0);       
        $body = $issue->getElementsByTagName("issue_body")->item(0);       
        $name->nodeValue = $newName;
        $body->nodeValue = $newBody;
        break;                                                                  
    }                                                                       
}
```

The rest of your code has more of the same problems, but hopefully that will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is my first major PHP project so I'm making a ton of simple errors it seems, especially after staring at my entire codebase for hours on end (Editing the XML elements is my last task before wrapping the project up).  Thanks for the feedback, it's a lot of help!

Comment: @ChrisDevWard: If you're interested in code-review, this is acceptable on the programmers website: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ . Please keep question on SO on topic, dumping large code chunks for debug requests is not.

Comment: @ChrisDevWard: Dandily appreciated.